# Why is my texture getting rotated by 90 degrees?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I am trying to draw a simple quad with a texture. I am using gluOrtho2d to set up an orthographic projection. I am unable to understand why the texture inside the quad is getting rotated 90° clockwise. The texture is a simple PNG file.

This is the problematic code :-

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
sf::Texture texture;


void draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;

    sf::Texture::bind(&texture);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(x + 400, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(x + 400, y + 400);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(x, y + 400);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glEnd();
}


int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), "problem");
    window.setActive(true);


    texture.loadFromFile("texture.png");

    glewInit();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    gluOrtho2D(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    bool isRunning = true;
    while(isRunning) {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }
        draw();
        window.display();
    }
}
```

This is the output. Here you can see the texture is rotated by 90°

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`glVertex*()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) calls "lock in" the current color/texture-coordinates/position for a vertex and hand off those values to the GL driver:

> `glVertex` commands are used within glBegin/glEnd pairs to specify point, line, and polygon vertices. **The current color, normal, texture coordinates, and fog coordinate are associated with the vertex when `glVertex` is called.**

The way you have it now:

```
glVertex2f(x, y);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
```

...that first `glVertex()` call is re-using the most recently set texture coordinates, those from the previous frame: `glTexCoord2f(0, 1)`

So you need to set texture coordinates for a vertex *before* the position:

```
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2f(x, y);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2f(x + 400, y);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2f(x + 400, y + 400);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2f(x, y + 400);
```